# How do I assign different style to Insert and Cancel buttons of a DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DetailsView in Insert mode:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="myButton" InsertText="My Insert text" />
```

Both buttons Insert/Cancel get the same style, of course.

**Is it possible to style these two separately to be one Blue and one Yellow?**

In FormView you can define the buttons separately like this:

```
<asp:Button CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" class="myButtonStyle1"  ID="myButtonID1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" />

<asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" class="myButtonStyle2"  ID="myButtonID2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Is there anything similar for DetailsView?

Comment: Can you post the html rendered by detailsview. You can set the style on the buttons using Javascript.

Comment: Okay, if I could give them names of my own, I could access them through C# code behind, right?
Here is the related HTML:

`<input type="submit" value="Insert" class="myButtonStyle1" name="ctl00$content1$DetailsView1$ctl10" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="myButtonStyle2" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content1$DetailsView1&#39;,&#39;Cancel$-1&#39;)"  />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to convert your "New, Insert, Cancel" CommandField into a TemplateField.  If you using the WYSIWYG editor, there is a button for this above the OK button.  This will generate the following (censored) code that you can easy style.

```
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="insertButton" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="cancelButton" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

NOTE: I added the CssClass attribute to the Buttons below with the CSS class names "insertButton, cancelButton", that can all be configured in your style sheet.

More notes:

1. When buttons are needed (NOT linkButtons) do not use the closing tag
   (`</asp:button>`) - replace it with an inline `/` mark. Otherwise, it won't work.
2. When using Insert only mode, the censored ItemTemplate is not
   needed — remove it.
3. Avoid having a ControlStyle control, otherwise it may cause class overrule.

Comment: Good work, thanks. I've updated your solution to match the one I actually use. See trailing notes too.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery):

```
<script src="../jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var list = $("input[type=button]");
        list.each(function (itemIndex) {
            if ($(this).val() == "Cancel")
            { $(this).addClass("Cancel"); }
            else {
                if ($(this).val() == "Insert")
                { $(this).addClass("Insert"); }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just add two classes ("Insert" & "Cancel") in your CSS file. 
For Eg.

```
 <style type="text/css">
.Insert {background-color:Red;}
    .Cancel {background-color:Black;}
</style>
```

Comment: Kapil Khandelwal- Where do I put that? Should I replace the "Insert" which is in the addClass with my class names (several class names per button)?

Comment: @Different111222 Just add two classes ("Insert" & "Cancel") in your CSS file. For Eg. `.Insert {background-color::red;} .Cancel {background-color::black;}`  Put the javascript code on your .aspx page

Comment: Kapil Khandelwal- I put the code in <script></script> in the head then in the body ContentPlaceHolder (not the same time), added the insert and cancel classes to the css, but nothing works...  Where do I exactly put the jQuery function (never used jQuery before), and can't I use my button's regular styles I use ("myButton myButtonStyle1")?

Comment: @Different111222 Have you added the reference of jQuery library on your page. If not download from here : http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery & add the reference above the jQuery function. I have updated my answer for the same.

Comment: @Different111222 I just missed one closing bracket. I have fixed that.

Comment: kapil-khandelwal - Your code didn't work, but thanks to u I'm using jQuery from time to time now, and reached the solution published here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kapil-khandelwal this is a solution using jQuery, that was in use until the newly added answer from Zachary:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("type") == "submit") {
                    if ($(this).val() == "Insert") { $(this).addClass("Insert"); };
                };
                if ($(this).attr("type") == "button") {
                    if ($(this).val() == "Cancel") { $(this).addClass("Cancel"); };
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
```